# Unable to calculate gradient with respect to trainable variables in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow. I am trying to solve differential equation dy_dx = -2xy with initial condition x(0)=1 over x=[-2,2] using a concept called Physics Informed Neural Network. When I am trying to calculate gradient with respect to trainable variable, it is giving 'none' value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.python import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential 

N = 200 # no. of points
a = -2.0
b = 2.0
x = np.arange(a, b, (b-a)/N).reshape((N,1))
xx= tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
y = np.zeros(N)
with tf.GradientTape() as tt:
    tt.watch(model.trainable_weights)
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as t:
        t.watch(xx)
        output = model(xx)
    result = output
    dy_dx = t.gradient(result, xx)
    l1=dy_dx + 2*x*model(xx) # loss funcn for the differential equation dy_dx +2xy.
    gg=np.array([0])
    l2=model.predict(gg) -1 # loss funcn for initial condition y(0)=1.
    fnl_loss=np.mean(l1**2) + l2**2 # total loss funcn
fnll= tf.convert_to_tensor(fnl_loss, dtype=tf.float32)   
grad = tt.gradient(fnll,model.trainable_weights)
print(grad)
```

Result:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: xx is not defined in your code, and it is the input to your model?

Comment: @ Dr. snoopy ,Sorry I forgot to add xx = tf.convert_to_tensor(x,dtype=tf.float32) in my code

Comment: You need to implement your loss using tensorflow functions, and the computation needs to be under the GradientTape object (currently it is not).

Comment: it is very simple. Invest some time on this webpage. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff